# Error al realizar llamada a SOAP web service mediane Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, webservice

Intento llamar un SOAP; http://crcind.com/csp/samples/SOAP.Demo.cls?soap_method=AddInteger&Arg1=10&Arg2=20
al cual se le pasan dos valores por la URL `(Arg1 y Arg2)`, los capturo por medio de dos inputs. Lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
onCallSOAP: function (oEvent) {

        var num1 = this.getView().byId("num1").getValue();
        var num2 = this.getView().byId("num2").getValue();
        var url = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://crcind.com/csp/samples/SOAP.Demo.cls?soap_method=AddInteger&Arg1="+num1+"&Arg2="+num2;
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            content: "text/xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: this.resSuccess,
            error: this.resError
            
        });
    },
    
    resSuccess: function(data, status, req){
        
        var responseTotal = "";
        var dataXML = req.responseText;
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(dataXML,"text/xml");
        responseTotal = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("AddIntengerResult")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        alert(responseTotal);
    },
    resError: function(data, status, req){
        debugger;
        console.log(data);
    },
```

Para la URL utilizo `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, ya que si no marca un error de que no se puede acceder.
Sin embargo nunca logro entrar a `resSuccess`, pero no sé por que, lo que me sale en consola es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

gracias de antemano

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` es una cabecera HTTP. No es algo que uno pueda incluir dentro de la URL como lo estás haciendo... Por eso nunca entra a success

Comment: ohh y no tienes idea de como puedo hacerle para que me funcione?

Comment: El `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` es una cabecera que devuelve el servidor para indicarle al navegador si está o no está permitido hacer una petición por ajax desde un dominio específico. Si no tienes acceso al servidor, no puedes hacer nada. Si tienes acceso al servidor solo es configurar tu dominio como un dominio permitido. O lo unico sería montar tu propio servidor al cual le enviaras la URL a consultar y fuera él el que hiciera la consulta y te regresara los datos consultados de vuelta (asi te saltarías la restricción de tu navegador).